# How to run simple ruby script (not RoR app) on heroku?

Tags: ruby, heroku, scheduler

I wonder about how can I run simple script on Heroku? Until now I have been working only with RoR app which I hosted on Heroku, but I never run there one simple script.

I would need just run simple ruby script which would be run by Scheduler. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rake` and the `scheduler` addon from Heroku.
Here is a comprehensive guide in the heroku docs.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler
Baiscally you create a rake task and select when to run it. It is quite simple.

Comment: Yes, but this is a way if I want to run a task in my Rails application, right? But I would need to create simple one ruby script, for this script create Heroku application, where I would deploy it. And this one simple script I would need to apply Scheduler. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. When you create a rake script, you give it a namespace, and in the scheduler console you put the namespace and frequency when it will run. No need to be inside a Rails Application. I have a Sinatra app with some rake scripts which run on scheduler this way.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just add blank Gemfile and Gemfile.lock so that heroku detects your app as a Ruby app.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: but which file will it enter by default?